# firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function Firebase react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments

I'm using this stripe extension and I am trying to pass the uid it gives me error `firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function` But I have Never seen this error before. please see the code below

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import firebase from 'firebase';


const firestore = firebase.firestore();

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if(user) {
console.log(user.uid) ;
}
});

export async function createCheckoutSession(uid){
  firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user){
      const checkoutSessionRef =  firestore
        .collection('customers')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('checkout_sessions')
        .add({
          price: 'price id',
          success_url: window.location.origin,
          cancel_url: window.location.origin,
      });
// Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
    checkoutSessionRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
      const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
      if (error) {
    // Show an error to your customer and 
    // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
      alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
    }
    if (sessionId) {
    // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
    // Init Stripe
    const stripe =   loadStripe('pk_test_1234');
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
    }
  });
  }
}
  )}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Inside `createCheckoutSession` you have `firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged`. That should be `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it gave the same error when I did this... do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: That seems unlikely. Can you edit your question to show the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(async () =>{
    await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
        console.log(user.uid) ;
    }
});
} )();
```

Comment: Do you have a firebase config object, and did you activate authentication in firebase console

Comment: yes, we did both. we have all the config set up in the firebase config folder, as well as activated on the firebase console side... the code is set up to have all the fields necessary like apiKey, authdomain, projectID, appID, etc etc

Comment: Are you using react.js so that i can help you easily

Comment: it gave the same error as before when I tried this solution... do you have any other suggestions?